# Question on infinite series from Introduction to Real Analysis by Robert Bartle [Chapter 9, Exercise 9.1, Question 6]

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We have to find an explicit partial sum to prove that the  series
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \ln\left( 1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ converges to $-\ln2$.

I tried various ways of writing the partial sums but could not prove this. Please help me find the partial sum and prove that the limit of that partial sum and hence this series will converge to $-\ln2$.

Thank you.

Comment: I hope that series does not start at $n=1$

Comment: $\ln (\dfrac{n^2-1}{n^2})=\ln(n+1)+\ln(n-1) -2\ln (n)$.Helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln (1-\frac 1{n^{2}})=\ln (\frac {n-1} n) -\ln (\frac n {n+1})$ which makes the partial sums  a telescopic sum. [Note that you cannot start the series with $n=1$].

The $N-$ the partial sum (starting with $n=2$) is $\ln (\frac 1 2) -\ln (\frac N {N+1})$ which tends to $ln (\frac 1 2)=-\ln 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\log\left(\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{n^2}\right)=\log(n+1)+\log(n-1)-2\log(n)$$
and telescope the series.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\log (1-1/k^2) =\log\left (\prod_{k=2}^{\infty} (1-1/k^2) \right)=\log( 1/2)=-\log 2.$$ Here, we have used
$$\prod_{k=2}^{\infty} (1-1/k^2)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Sir, can you show me how $\prod_{k=2}^{\infty} (1-1/k^2)=\frac{1}{2}$? I know it is a different topic, so even a link of the proof will be fine. Thank you.

Comment: Tis product is actually  a telescopic product $(1-1/2)(1+1/2)(1-1/3)(1+1/3)(1-1/4)(1+1/4)....(1-1/n)(1+1/n)= (1/2). (n+1)/n.$ When $n \rightarrow \infty$ we get $1/2$.